# Understanding regression bootstrap confidence interval in multiple comparison

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, p-value, bootstrap, multiple-comparisons

Let's say I have 100 subjects split into two age groups (young/older) and each have a single value given for performance on a memory test.

I plot a linear regression for each age group, to test if memory scores can predict some Y variable, Y2 variable, and/or Y3 variable.

That requires 6 total regressions and thus multiple comparisons increase the chance of a type type I error.

Is it appropriate, given the somewhat small N, to use bootstrap regression instead of a p value correction?

If so, does plotting the confidence interval of such bootstrap regression over the original regression, address the multiple comparison issue?  In other words, how would I use a bootstrap regression to address the multiple comparisons issue and specifically relate it to the original regression?

Answer (score 0):

By itself, bootstrapping does not address the multiple comparisons issue. However, by appropriately bootstrapping certain maximal statistics, you can indeed control the usual multiple comparisons error rates, at least approximately. See the book *Resampling-Based Multiple Testing: Examples and Methods for p-Value Adjustment,* in particular, the chapter "Continuous Data Applications: Multivariate Analysis."

https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Resampling+Based+Multiple+Testing:+Examples+and+Methods+for+p+Value+Adjustment-p-9780471557616

See also the research article, "On using the bootstrap for multiple comparisons."
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10543406.2011.607751